# Check for INVITE after REGISTER in SIP

Tags: c#, sip, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I've been developing a C# Xamarin application with **PJSIP**, and I have encountered a small (or large) obstacle. The system I currently have set-up is that a user will get a notification of an incoming call, which allows them to click on the notification and open the app. The app will then register with the SIP server using SIP credentials, and will ideally receive an INVITE message, allowing them to answer the incoming call. However, this is not at all how it is working. If the app is registered with the SIP server before the INVITE is sent, the call is received fine. However, if the app is registered *after* the INVITE is sent, it never gets received or recognized by the client. Is there a way to manually check for an INVITE message using SIP, or is this a functionality that simply does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how the SIP REGISTER method works,

The purpose of the SIP REGISTER method is to let the SIP server know where to reach that user - Which IP Address & Port should it send the SIP INVITE to.

If you haven't registered, your SIP server won't know which IP address in the whole internet to sent the SIP INVITE for the call to when it wants to call it.

While you can setup your app to listen for incoming SIP INVITES, and that'll work fine, the server still needs to know which IP address and port to send it to, so you'd need another mechanism to tell this SIP server which IP address and port to send SIP INVITEs to, but that's a problem that SIP REGISTER was setup to solve so it's probably easiest just to use the SIP REGISTER function.

[I wrote a blog post on how the SIP REGISTRAR function works in a bit more detail if you're curious.](https://nickvsnetworking.com/what-is-a-sip-registrar/)

Answer (score 0):

When the SIP server receives an incoming call (INVITE message) it needs to know where to forward it to. That's why your application needs to register at the server: this creates a mapping between a SIP URI (user) and its contact address (IP). When the SIP server receives the INVITE it checks if a mapping for the message's Request-URI exists, and if so forwards the message to the corresponding contact address.

If no mapping exists at the time the SIP server receives the INVITE message the SIP server will simply end the INVITE transaction by returning a final response like 404 Not Found. Your client won't be notified of the incoming INVITE message.

If you have access to the SIP server you could create a static mapping in the SIP server between your application's URI and its contact address. That means your application won't have to register anymore. It's not very flexible but it will help you in this case. Mind however, when using a static mapping the SIP server will probably always forward incoming INVITE messages. Even when your application isn't running.